# Failed to set memory limit to 134217728 bytes (Current memory usage is ______ bytes)

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-8.1

In my server, the initial memory limit configured is 128M.
Occasionally, we needs to do something that consumes lots of memory (such as downloading a very big pdf file via mpdf library or running an insert command via sqlite for backup and restore purposes).

We usually either set the limit to higher, or unlimited (case by case basis), and at the end of script, we set it back to original (128M).

Something like this

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // '-1' or '1024M' for example

//do my code that requires huge memory

ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); //reset the memory at end of code
```

Everything was working well (it still is working correctly as of now). But after upgrading to PHP8.1 recently, I start to get warnings in my error logs

Failed to set memory limit to 134217728 bytes (Current memory usage is 226242560 bytes) /var/www/file_location_that_calls_ini_set_memory_limit

So my question is, is this a concern/issue to my system? is there a proper way to solve this issue? Or should i just mute/silent the error logs when its this phrase?

This is also not always replicate-able, and happens randomly, even when generating and downloading the same pdf.

Comment: Its a bug, you have to upgrade your PhP to the latest version, more info here https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8116

Comment: @Grumpy I am using PHP8.1.8 (we kinda just upgraded few days ago).

Comment: you opened the ticket again, good, thats the way to go, no easy solution for this one.